# Electron photon interaction potential in old fashioned perturbation theory (OFPT)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, perturbation-theory

In [this PDF](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1097985.files/I-4-OldFashionedPerturbationTheory.pdf#page=3) on old fashioned perturbation theory (OFPT) we find from equation (14) the potential describing the interaction between the electron and photon:

$$ V = \frac{1}{2}e \int \mathrm{d}^3x\, \psi_e(x)\phi(x)\psi_e(x) \tag{14}$$

where $\phi=photon. $

My question is why $V$ looks as it does and where exactly does it come from?

Comment: Is this not just a standard vertex from a Feynman diagram?

Comment: This is a caricature of the cubic interaction between electrons and photons $e\bar{\psi} /\!\!\!\! A \psi$ where the fermionic and vector fields are represented by scalar fields. This model is discussed by Coleman in his famous QFT lectures.

Comment: @Danu maybe it is...I never went through potential in qft, only lagrangians.